# Strange new directory structure in Django-1.4.1?

Tags: django, directory-structure, django-1.4

I've just installed the latest version of Django (1.4.1) on Ubuntu 12.04. The new docs and everything else I've been able to find seems to think the directory structure should be as follows:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

However, running `$ django-admin.py startproject mysite` resulted in the following directory structure:

```
mysite/
    __init.py__
    manage.py
    settings.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    templates/
    urls.py
```

There seems to be little difference between `mysite/urls.py` and `mysite/mysite/urls.py`, the difference being in line 1 of the files, where the `mysite/urls.py` import statement begins `from django.conf.urls.defaults` instead of `from django.conf.urls`. There is similarly little difference between the two `settings.py` files.

My question is:

- Is this the result of a bug
- Did I accidentally download the trunk which is displaying (for some reason) an incorrect version number
- Or is it supposed to be like this, and if so, why, what's the difference between the similar files, and how should I use them?

**EDIT:** Oberon's answer solved the problem for me (thanks!), but I'd still be interested in knowing what the problem was in the first place, if anybody has any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've met the same problem with it, and what I do is to remove django and reinstall it
And it works like the first one you've shown.